# nuxt-auth setting user object after login

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

im using the nuxt-auth module.
I've got it to work so far. I am able to login properly.
But whenever i login, the user object in my store does not get set.
It seems like my API is getting called without parameters so it does not know which user to set.

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: 'token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'token'
          },
          user: {
            url: 'microservice/user',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: false
          },
          logout: false
        }
      },
      watchLoggedIn: true,
      resetOnError: true
    }
  },
```

logging in

```
 await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
          data: {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.passwort
          }
        })
```

example API-User

```
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/user/102",
  "query": "",
  "response": {
    "type": "single",
    "payload": {
      "id": 102,
      "firstname": "super",
      "name": "test",
      "username": "stest1",
     //some data
    }
  }
}
```

After retrieving a token and setting it, my app sends a request without query/parameters to my user-API. Either im doing something wrong, or am just too dumb too see the right way to set my user. However, if i set my user-Route to for example 'microservice/user/102' it is able to retrieve that one specific user.

Hoping anyone can help! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set it propertyName for user endpoint

```
user: {
    url: 'microservice/user',
    method: 'get',
    propertyName: payload
},
```